# compare count columns not recognized

Tags: sql, group-by, count, compare, sql-order-by

I have some Columns whose values depend on sums for the row info.  However, when I get to the where statement, it won't let me compare those values so I can just display the ones with issues. See comment *** in query for issue.

This is what my query looks like:

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT
    p.ID
    ,p.Last 
    ,p.First 
    ,SUM(distinct CASE WHEN pf.facility in ('S','H','E') then 1 ELSE 0 END) as facility_count 
    ,SUM(distinct CASE WHEN (fs.ques_id = 59 AND pf.facility in ('S','H','E') ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS sum_qst_59
    FROM person p
inner JOIN person_facilities pf ON p.ID = pf.ID
LEFT JOIN dbo.ADD_ANSW fs ON p.id = fs.id 

WHERE 
    pf.Facility in ('s', 'h', 'e')
    AND
    pf.status in ('Active')
    AND
    facility_count != sum_qst_59 ***--this doesn't work. Says no such columns***

group by p.id, Last, First
order by Last
```

I saw [compare counts](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/195795/postgres-sql-compare-count-of-rows-returning-where-a-b-or-b-doesnt-exist), but I can't figure out how to get that to work for my query and output.  Any help would be appreciated.

In other words, there are people that belong in multiple facilities (which I'm counting their facilities for each person).  Plus I'm counting how many times they have answer 59 for those same facilities.  Then I'm comparing the counts because they should be the same if they answered it for all facilities.  Then I'm finding where the counts don't match so we can fix it.

*Update -
I'm trying what was suggested but it has the error

```
Incorrect syntax near keyword 'having'

SELECT 
    DISTINCT
    p.ID
    ,p.Last 
    ,p.First 
   --change in having and sum line below
    ,having SUM(distinct CASE WHEN pf.facility in ('S','H','E') then 1 ELSE 0 END) as facility_count 
<>
    SUM(distinct CASE WHEN (fs.ques_id = 59 AND pf.facility in ('S','H','E') ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS sum_qst_59
    FROM person p
inner JOIN person_facilities pf ON p.ID = pf.ID
LEFT JOIN dbo.ADD_ANSW fs ON p.id = fs.id 

WHERE 
    pf.Facility in ('s', 'h', 'e')
    AND
    pf.status in ('Active')

group by p.id, Last, First
order by Last
```

Update 2: Also tried the following but still incorrect syntax near having -

```
   SELECT 
        DISTINCT
        p.ID
        ,p.Last 
        ,p.First 
        ,SUM(distinct CASE WHEN pf.facility in ('S','H','E') then 1 ELSE 0 END) as facility_count 
        ,SUM(distinct CASE WHEN (fs.ques_id = 59 AND pf.facility in ('S','H','E') ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS sum_qst_59
        FROM person p
    inner JOIN person_facilities pf ON p.ID = pf.ID
    LEFT JOIN dbo.ADD_ANSW fs ON p.id = fs.id 

    WHERE 
        pf.Facility in ('s', 'h', 'e')
        AND
        pf.status in ('Active')
       --change in having and sum line below
        AND --this has incorrect syntax near having
         having SUM(distinct CASE WHEN pf.facility in ('S','H','E') then 1 ELSE 0 END) 
<>
        SUM(distinct CASE WHEN (fs.ques_id = 59 AND pf.facility in ('S','H','E') ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 

    group by p.id, Last, First
    order by Last
```

Answer (score 1):

Column aliases cannot be used to reference expressions in a `WHERE` clause. But even if they could you'd be wrong as filters that should take place after aggregation have to be put in a `HAVING` clause.

Try:

```
...
HAVING sum(CASE
             WHEN pf.facility IN ('S','H','E') THEN
               1
             ELSE
               0
           END)
       <>
       sum(CASE
             WHEN fs.ques_id = 59
                  AND pf.facility IN ('S','H','E') THEN
               1
             ELSE
               0
           END)
...
```

`sum(DISTINCT ...)` also doesn't seem to make sense. And the `DISTINCT` in the outer `SELECT` also could be useless.

Comment: But then I wouldn't be seeing the count columns in my output anymore, right? It just compares counts?  I'd like to see the counts too.

Comment: @Michele: You mean using an expression in a `HAVING` clause makes a column in the result, that also consists of the same expression, magically disappear? No, it doesn't.

Comment: @Michele: Because you have an `AND` after which nothing follows in your `WHERE` clause. And the `HAVING` clause has to come after the `GROUP BY` clause, **not** after the `WHERE` clause as you have it.